# Windows batch file Infinite Loop hang while running Python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a very simple Windows batch file that should run Python, wait 5 seconds, echo searching, loop. 
The Python file is checking my email and either creating files or deleting them and then emailing me when conditions are correct for me to trade. 
It works great but overnight I wake to see it is sitting stalled. If I press enter it starts up again and runs for some time.

Batch code is

```
:loop
timeout 5

"C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" "TValert.py"

echo "Scan Complete"

goto loop
```

and python code is

```py
import imaplib,email,time
import smtplib
import os.path
from os import path
#mail imap
user = 'Trader@gmail.com'
pwd = 'password'
imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'
con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL (imap_url)
con.login(user,pwd)
con.select('INBOX')


def deleteEmail(user, pwd, IMAP):

    typ, data = con.search(None, 'ALL')
    for num in data[0].split():
        con.store(num, '+FLAGS', r'(\Deleted)')
        con.expunge()



print("Scanning Email....")
time.sleep(1.5)
result, no = con.search(None,'(FROM "god" SUBJECT "Come Home")')
result, long = con.search(None,'(FROM "tradingview" SUBJECT "Rosie Long")')
result, short = con.search(None,'(FROM "tradingview" SUBJECT "Rosie Short")')
result, close_long = con.search(None,'(FROM "tradingview" SUBJECT "Rosie Close Long")')
result, close_short = con.search(None,'(FROM "tradingview" SUBJECT "Rosie Close Short")')
result, TwoRiskOff = con.search(None,'(FROM "tradingview" SUBJECT "$2 Risk Off")')    
result, NineRiskOff = con.search(None,'(FROM "tradingview" SUBJECT "$9 Risk Off")')    
result, TwoWhite = con.search(None,'(FROM "tradingview" SUBJECT "$2 White")')    
result, NineWhite = con.search(None,'(FROM "tradingview" SUBJECT "$9 White")')      
result, TwoBlack = con.search(None,'(FROM "tradingview" SUBJECT "$2 Black")')    
result, NineBlack = con.search(None,'(FROM "tradingview" SUBJECT "$9 Black")')      

if long != no:
    if path.exists("Long.txt"):
        mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        mail.ehlo()
        mail.starttls()
        mail.login(user,pwd)
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format("ERROR DUPLICATE LONG SIGNAL","ERROR DUPLICATE LONG SIGNAL" )    
        mail.sendmail(user,"2062348485@mms.att.net",message)
        mail.close

    else:
        if path.exists("Short.txt"):
            os.remove("Short.txt")
            mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
            mail.ehlo()
            mail.starttls()
            mail.login(user,pwd)
            message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format("Close Long Position","Close Long Position" )    
            mail.sendmail(user,"2062348485@mms.att.net",message)
            mail.close

        else:
            if path.exists("TwoWhite.txt"):
                if path.exists("NineWhite.txt"):
                    open("Long.txt","w+")
                    mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
                    mail.ehlo()
                    mail.starttls()
                    mail.login(user,pwd)
                    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format("BUY NOW!", "BUY NOW!")    
                    mail.sendmail(user,"2062348485@mms.att.net",message)
                    mail.close
                else:
                    print("No Correlation")
            else:
                print("No Correlation")





if short != no:
    if path.exists("Short.txt"):
        mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        mail.ehlo()
        mail.starttls()
        mail.login(user,pwd)
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format("ERROR DUPLICATE SHORT SIGNAL","ERROR DUPLICATE SHORT SIGNAL" )    
        mail.sendmail(user,"2062348485@mms.att.net",message)
        mail.close

    else:
        if path.exists("Long.txt"):
            os.remove("Long.txt")
            mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
            mail.ehlo()
            mail.starttls()
            mail.login(user,pwd)
            message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format("Close Long Position","Close Long Position" )    
            mail.sendmail(user,"2062348485@mms.att.net",message)
            mail.close

        else:
            if path.exists("TwoBlack.txt"):
                if path.exists("NineBlack.txt"):
                    open("Short.txt","w+")
                    mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
                    mail.ehlo()
                    mail.starttls()
                    mail.login(user,pwd)
                    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format("SELL NOW!", "SELL NOW!")    
                    mail.sendmail(user,"2062348485@mms.att.net",message)
                    mail.close
                else:
                    print("No Correlation")
            else:
                print("No Correlation")





if TwoRiskOff !=no:
    try:
        if path.exists("TwoBlack.txt"):
            os.remove("TwoBlack.txt")
        if path.exists("TwoWhite.txt"):
            os.remove("TwoWhite.txt")
    except:
        print("Error While Running Two Risk Off")

if NineRiskOff !=no:
    try:
        if path.exists("NineBlack.txt"):
            os.remove("NineBlack.txt")
        if path.exists("NineWhite.txt"):
            os.remove("NineWhite.txt")
    except:
        print("Error While Running Two White")

if TwoWhite !=no:
    try:
        open("TwoWhite.txt","w+")
        if path.exists("TwoBlack.txt"):
            os.remove("TwoBlack.txt")
    except:
        print("Error While running Two White")


if TwoBlack !=no:
    try:
        open("TwoBlack.txt","w+")
        if path.exists("TwoWhite.txt"):
            os.remove("TwoWhite.txt")    
    except:
        print("Error While running Two Black")

if NineWhite !=no:
    try:
        open("NineWhite.txt","w+")
        if path.exists("NineBlack.txt"):
            os.remove("NineBlack.txt")
    except:
        print("Error While running Nine White")

if NineBlack !=no:
    try:
        open("NineBlack.txt","w+")  
        if path.exists("NineWhite.txt"):
            os.remove("NineWhite.txt")
    except:
        print("Error While running Nine Black") 

deleteEmail(user,pwd,con)


exit()
```

Comment: It's how IB's code disconnects the socket.  They've made some changes in the code  but I don't know what release it's going to be in.  You can just ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to a friend of mine today and he instructed me to run the python file via Powershell and it is working perfectly so far.